How do I connect to my database from Java/JSP when upgrading to Jakarta?
I am trying to migrate code that I wrote 15 years ago to a new server.
One of the changes is the javax.* package naming changed to jakarta.* naming as part of Oracle transferring Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation to became Jakarta EE. That threw me for a loop for a while.
I have made progress in getting my code to work, but now I am stuck when I try to connect to my database. Unfortunately, I don't remember much about how I set this up and I don't often do server configuration, so I am out of my depth. Here is what I know:
I try to get a connection to my database with this:
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource pool = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql-prod");

I then try to get a connection with:
conn = pool.getConnection();
and at that point the following lines show up in logfile:
[PROD http-nio-80-exec-8  16/05/2024 14:02:13:205]  16/05/2024 14:02:13:205: Exception caught in doPost on server
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.doPost(AlgoraphServer.java:220)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:465)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:529)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:710)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.openConnection(AlgoraphServer.java:320)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.getProblemFamilies(AlgoraphServer.java:1512)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:298)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:59)
        ... 34 more
[PROD http-nio-80-exec-8  16/05/2024 14:02:13:207] 05/16/2024 14:02:13 Error on SERVER from request at IP 209.140.240.79: null

[PROD http-nio-80-exec-8  16/05/2024 14:02:13:208] Pool:org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@6780cb54
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:465)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:529)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:710)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.openConnection(AlgoraphServer.java:320)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.logStuff(AlgoraphServer.java:3124)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.logServerError(AlgoraphServer.java:3159)
        at cusack.hcg.server.AlgoraphServer.doPost(AlgoraphServer.java:263)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:298)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:59)
        ... 31 more
[PROD http-nio-80-exec-9  16/05/2024 14:02:13:243] Handling request from IP 209.140.240.79

I have copied the various config files over and made what I think are appropriate changes. For instance, I have the following in context.xml:
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="SESSIONS.ser" />
    -->

    <!--Resource name="jdbc/mysql-prod" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            username="fakename" password="fakepassword" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql-prod?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />-->
</Context>

I am not sure what else I should be looking at--as I said, I am way out of my depth on server configuration, and at this point the logfiles are not providing me with enough information to know where else to be looking.
Any ideas?

Your datasource config (<!--Resource name...) is commented out. Uncomment it

@g00se Oops. Someone else did some of the updating and I didn't look closely enough at the files to notice that! I've now got another error, but one step closer it seems! Thanks.

@g00se was correct--it was commented code in a config file. Now the problem is with database permissions, which means I am one step closer!
